# Adding base class type hints when subclassing a container

Tags: python, type-hinting

When I subclass a container, how can I specify type hints for the container part of my definition? I mean something like the (currently not supported) following:

```
from typing import Dict

class MyDict(dict: Dict[str, int]):
    def __init__(...):
...
```

That way, when I am trying to add, remove, etc... objects to my dict through the interface inherited from the base class, it could be type checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) that the form is

```
from typing import Dict

class Test(Dict[str, int]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.update({'a': 5})

test = Test()
print(test) # prints {'a': 5}
```

Comment: Ok, but this one spits an error: class MyDict(Dict[str, int]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.update(dict())   It says: Instance of 'MyDict' has not 'update' member. ¿Why is this error?

Comment: @Stagrovin: the code shown in the edited answer works for me on python 3.6

Comment: Thanks, finally I've managed to see where the problem was: It was pylint, not mypy who complains about a supposed "non existent member" (update), as I've both configured in my editor